# Use ifelse and is.null to test for NULL values

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(gene = structure(1:6, .Label = c("128up", "14-3-3epsilon", 
"14-3-3zeta", "140up", "18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602", "18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861"
), class = "factor"), fpkm = list(NULL, 0.4, NA_real_, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("gene", "fpkm"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
                 gene fpkm
1               128up NULL
2       14-3-3epsilon  0.4
3          14-3-3zeta   NA
4               140up NULL
5 18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602 NULL
6 18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861 NULL
```

I would like to add a new column, `level` based on the value in `fpkm`. In cases where the value is `NULL` or `NA` I would like the value to be 'not_expressed`, else`expressed`.

I'm using `mutate` to achieve this, for `NA` and `NULL` values separately, but this does not have the desired effect on `NULL` values:

`mutate(df, level = ifelse(is.na(fpkm), 'not_expressed' , 'expressed'))`

```
                 gene fpkm         level
1               128up NULL     expressed
2       14-3-3epsilon  0.4     expressed
3          14-3-3zeta   NA not_expressed # Expected
4               140up NULL     expressed
5 18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602 NULL     expressed
6 18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861 NULL     expressed
```

---

```
  mutate(df, level = ifelse(is.null(fpkm), 'not_expressed' , 'expressed'))

                 gene fpkm     level
1               128up NULL expressed
2       14-3-3epsilon  0.4 expressed
3          14-3-3zeta   NA expressed
4               140up NULL expressed
5 18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602 NULL expressed
6 18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861 NULL expressed
```

I can't work out why this isn't working - `is.null(unlist(test$fpkm[1]))` returns `TRUE`

I've also tried:
`ifelse(is.null(df$fpkm), 'not_expressed', 'expressed')`

and:
`ifelse(is.null(unlist(df$fpkm)), 'not_expressed', 'expressed')`

...neither of which work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R is good enough for this:

```
> df$level <-  ifelse( df$fpkm == 'NULL' | is.na(df$fpkm), 'not_expressed', 'expressed')
> df
                 gene fpkm         level
1               128up NULL not_expressed
2       14-3-3epsilon  0.4     expressed
3          14-3-3zeta   NA not_expressed
4               140up NULL not_expressed
5 18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602 NULL not_expressed
6 18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861 NULL not_expressed
```

Comment: So when we test `L == "NA"` for a list `L`, this is like R silently applies `as.character` to `L` ? +1, I didn't know that. Therefore I think your third test `is.na(df$fpkm)` is useless.

Comment: Actually, just only use `is.null(df$fpkm) | is.na(df$fpkm)`. Testing for equality (`==`) should not be done with `NULL` or `NA`.

Comment: @Laterow try `L <- list(1, NULL, NA); L == "NULL"`

Comment: @Laterow Wrong. `is.null(df$fpkm)` returns `FALSE`, because the *list*  `df$fpkm` is not `NULL`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ```> is.na(df$fpkm)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE```

Comment: @amrrs Yes, but `df$fpkm == "NA"` has the same output, so `is.na(df$fpkm)` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The last statement is a clue to your issue. You had to `unlist` to achieve the right result

```
unlist(test$fpkm[1])
```

`fpkm` is saved as a list in your data frame (and not a vector, which is typical)

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ gene: Factor w/ 6 levels "128up","14-3-3epsilon",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ fpkm:List of 6
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : num 0.4
  ..$ : num NA
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
```

You can get the right result with

```
  mutate(df, level = ifelse(map_lgl(df$fpkm, ~is.null(.x) || is.na(.x)), 'not_expressed' , 'expressed'))
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I convert it into a vector instead of a list?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to unlist without losing your NULL values. I recommend going back to when you created your data frame. You might have used `lapply`, which will return a list. You could use `sapply` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Convert *NULL* to *NA*, then use `ifelse`:

```
# Convert NULL to NA
df$fpkm[ sapply(df$fpkm, is.null) ] <- NA

# I would also drop the list, it is up to you.
# df$fpkm <- unlist(df$fpkm)

# Then use ifelse as usual
df$level <-  ifelse(is.na(df$fpkm), "not_expressed", "expressed")

# result
df
#                  gene fpkm         level
# 1               128up   NA not_expressed
# 2       14-3-3epsilon  0.4     expressed
# 3          14-3-3zeta   NA not_expressed
# 4               140up   NA not_expressed
# 5 18SrRNA-Psi:CR41602   NA not_expressed
# 6 18SrRNA-Psi:CR45861   NA not_expressed
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, you can try finding out the length of the column values.
Instead of :

```
mutate(df, level = ifelse(is.na(fpkm), 'not_expressed' , 'expressed'))
```

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
mutate(df, level = if_else(str_length(fpkm)>0, 'expressed','not_expressed'))
```